# Why can I binding data using android:background="@{!aHomeViewModel.isHaveRecord? #FFFFF: #F3F3F8}"?

Tags: android, android-livedata

I'm using LiveData in layout file XML in  Android Studio, Code A and Code work well.

But Code C can't be compiled, how can I fix it?

**Error Information**

*expected, got '#'*

**Code A**

```
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
      ...                
      android:visibility="@{aHomeViewModel.isHaveRecord? View.VISIBLE: View.GONE}"
   />
```

**Code B**

```
  <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
      ...           
      android:background="#F3F3F8"     
   />
```

**Code C**

```
  <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
      ...           
      android:background="@{!aHomeViewModel.isHaveRecord? #FFFFFF: #F3F3F8}"     
   />
```

Comment: #FFFFF is not a color. There are only 5 F's

Comment: Thank! I still get the error `<expr> expected, got '#' ` after I have fixed it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

colors.xml

```
<resources>
    <color name="colorOne">#f3f3f8</color>
    <color name="colorTwo">#ffffff</color>
</resources>
```

Then in your xml layout

```
android:background="@{!aHomeViewModel.isHaveRecord ? @color/colorOne : @color/colorTwo }">
```

Answer (score 1):

Databinding cannot deal with hardcoded hex-values.

Your best option is using:

```
android:background="@{aHomeViewModel.isHaveRecord ? @color/record : @color/noRecord}"
```

Alternatively you could try using the integer color value. It might take the integer value. If not, the line above is your only way to go.

```
// (FFFFFF)16 = (16777215)10
// (F3F3F8)16 = (15987704)10
android:background="@{aHomeViewModel.isHaveRecord ? 16777215 : 15987704}"
```

(https://www.binaryhexconverter.com/hex-to-decimal-converter)

Answer (score -1):

I think there's no logical for `not` / `!` at [data binding expression](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/expressions#expression_language)


Maybe you can swap the return value for the background instead?

```
   <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
      ...           
      android:background="@{aHomeViewModel.isHaveRecord ? #F3F3F8: #FFFFFF}"     
   />
```